# Why does jquery-csv output '[]' from my csv?

Tags: jquery, jquery-csv

My code is

```
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="jquery.csv.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        data = $.csv.toObjects("testi.csv");
        console.log(data)
    </script>
```

and my code returns [], as if the array was empty.

I tried another file and with 'simple' values so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Please include an example of some CSV data that results in an empty array.

Comment: Can you also provide a CDN or other source for `jquery.csv.js`, including the version you are using

Comment: A very quick test (https://jsfiddle.net/c8afu72m/) shows it does this if it can't find the file `testi.csv` - I have *no idea* where it's looking for that file, other than it's on the client.  **edit** it's not a file, it needs to be a csv *string* - with a string, it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/c8afu72m/1/

Comment: [`$.csv.toObjects(string)`](https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv/blob/main/docs/api.md#csvtoobjects) expects a string containing CSV, not a filename.

Comment: 1) Where is your `"testi.csv"` file located.  2) Why do think the browser would know where this file is.  3) What happens if you pass a csv *string*

Comment: If you want to read the CSV from a file, you need to do that *before* calling `$.csv.toObjects()`, and pass the result as the argument.

Comment: if the file is on the server, use AJAX to fetch it. If it's on the client, use the FileReader API (this requires the user to select the file, you can't read from a filename directly in the browser).